# Stack Wars: The Phantom Edit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I got [this edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8958445) today. After reviewing it, I wasn't sure I'd voted correctly, so I went back to the review page to see what other reviewers had done. But when I went back, it showed that I hadn't reviewed it yet.

So I did my review again, expecting an error message. The second review also seemed to work fine, but going back to the page still showed it as unreviewed by me. I tried a few more times, with no more success. Visiting the question page didn't show any pending edits either.

Eventually, while testing accepts and rejects (both of which failed multiple times) it began working normally again, but I'm confused about what happened. Is this something anyone has seen before? Was it a bug, or should I just [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: To my recollection, it doesn't show who reviewed the edit until it's been accepted or rejected.

Comment: I see only one review recorded. Going back in your browser *without reloading* will not reload the review implicitly. You'll see the form as it was presented to you *as cached by your browser*. Any subsequent 'reviews' are ignored.

Comment: @Makoto in my experience, it will always show me the reviewers as soon as I've done the review. Plus, that wouldn't explain why there was no pending edit shown on the question page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've gone back to previous reviews in the same way dozens of times before though, and never seen this. And the times when I've managed to review twice, I've always gotten an error message the second time. I suppose it's possible it's just a quirk of my browser this time, but it was definitely out of the ordinary.

Comment: I can't say that I've ever seen that...then again, it's been a moment since I really went into the trenches of the review queue.

Comment: @Makoto: About that edit, not the mechanics: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300372/what-to-do-with-accepted-answers-that-were-valid-when-the-op-asked-but-not-anym

Comment: Go on then, have a vote just for the title:)