# What to do with accepted answers that were valid when the OP asked, but not anymore

Tags: discussion

I have run across a few questions on SO that were answered, but for whatever reason the answer no longer works. This morning I came across this one.

[Is there an easy way to check the .NET Framework version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-the-net-framework-version/951915#951915)

the accepted answer relies on a Registry layout that is only valid from .NET framework versions 1 to 4, and though it might have some usefulness now, its ability to impact users has already started to wan as can be seen by the bounty now on the question for a way to get the answer to work in .NET versions 4.5+.

I added an answer for the bounty question, and then added an edit to the accepted answer so that folks who land there from SO search or Google will know the versions for which the answer is good(1-4) and the version(4.5) at which they would have to try something else. I also gave a reference to the MS site that demonstrated how to do it for all versions.

[My suggestion was rejected 3 to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8958445) with the rejectors selecting:

> "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer"

How should we deal with answers that are lossing relevance especially in the case where the answer may be relevant for a little while longer, but is clearly not the answer that would be sought by folks going forward who find the page through either the SO search or Google?

An edit on the answer letting folks know that the accepted answer relies on a paradigm that is changing / has changed seemed appropriate, but 3 out of 4 reviewers disagreed.

Update:

Bill made a good point about the content of the edit so I thought I'd share.

> This accepted answer relies upon a registry layout that only exists in the .Net Framework for versions 1.0 through 4.0 it will not work for versions 4.5 and higher. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx#net_c)

Update:

While [Good question, old version-dependent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) is essentially the same question. It doesn't address why this edit approach is wrong. in fact it recommends it as an approach in both the comments and the second highest rated answer (14 up versus 36 up).

Comment: Oddly enough, your edit was discussed (tangentially) on [this other meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300370/stack-wars-the-phantom-edit).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Didn't see that and it didn't come up as a suggestion while I was typing, but the thing I find interesting is that the comments attached to that question and at least one well rated answer are to do what I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating information in an old answer [is acceptable according to the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).  Your edit fits these two "common reasons for edits":

> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

Reviewers are hesitant to approve edits that appear to change the underlying answers.  So these kinds of edits have be judged more on technical accuracy instead of just presentation/formatting.  It's often just easier to reject these kinds of edits as "clearly conflicts with author's intent" or "attempt to reply" rather than judge the accuracy of the edit.  Too often, other users try to edit these well-established, highly upvoted answers with bogus edits.  I think reviewers are sometimes jaded from past experiences and err on the side of caution in cases like these.

Because of your informative edit description, I did actually visit the MSDN link provided, and I approved your edit.  And according to [a previous meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300370/stack-wars-the-phantom-edit), another reviewer almost approved it, but wavered into rejecting it instead.

Basically, your edit was acceptable and happened to be rejected.  But the actions suggested in the rejection reason are other good solutions for updating this old post.  Actually providing a new answer that handles the new version(s) is more helpful than merely mentioning that the old solution won't work for on the new version(s).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I agree with the reviewers, but that depends on what you wrote in your suggested edit. Providing a new, separate answer to address newer versions of software is definitely correct. Editing the originally accepted answer to point out new developments doesn't seem wrong, though. I guess put that in a comment and ask the author of the original answer to include it? I wouldn't think that that would be a controversial edit, but it does depend on your wording and formatting.

Comment: I added the edit text to the question so folks can see. as for the comment and hope the author makes an edit him / her self. I did think about that. It's probably a good idea in theory, but I don't have a lot of faith that it would garner a lot of follow through.

Comment: And now I have to eat the words on follow through. The author just revised the question.

Comment: @SemicolonsandDuctTape: Wonderful, the comment did its work.